# Mailwatch Quarantine Not Showing Contents

Tags: php, debian

I have setup a mail gateway using MailScanner and have now setup MailWatch to be able to monitor the emails passing through.
It seems as though MailWatch's Quarantine is not showing me the contents of the quarantine. It does show me the recent emails as they pass through. But if I browse to the quarantine and select today's date it just says: `No quarantined messages found`

I am not sure why I am not seeing anything as I have done the setup exactly how the MailWatch.org website states I should.
Also, not sure if it is important, but I am running the following setup:

- Debian 7
- Postfix
- Mailscanner * Latest
- MailWatch * Latest

How can I find the cause?
From what I read it sounds like permissions. But I am not sure what I can/should change them to as as I don't want to break mailscanner.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

Change permissions for quarantine folder... Not sure about Debian but in Centos it is in /var/spool/MailScanner/quarantine. It should be owned by user postfix and group should be group that your web server is in (apache in Centos but, again, not sure about Debian). Access rights should be 770.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Found**

It seems that when the server reboots mailscanner tries to launch before mysq has completely started causing mailwatch sql logging to crash.

Simplest solution is to stop mailscanner, end the processes that may still be running and start mailscanner service back up again.
Resolves it immediately.